# Unable to get the fetched data in txtView

Tags: java, android, json

*I am trying to build an android app in which I want to display a data fetched from a url. I tried it using JSON. It doesn't shows any error but I couldn't get the result. This is how I tried:-*

```
//MainActivity.java

package com.example.login1;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

//URL to get JSON Array
private static String url = "http://demo.vtiger.com/webservice.php?operation=getchallenge&username=admin";
//JSON Node Names
private static final String TAG_RESULT = "result";
private static final String TAG_TOKEN = "token";
JSONArray token = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
  // Creating new JSON Parser
  JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
 // Getting JSON from URL
 JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
 try {
  // Getting JSON Array
  token = json.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULT);
  JSONObject c = token.getJSONObject(0);
  // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
  String token = c.getString(TAG_TOKEN);
  //Importing TextView
  final TextView gettoken = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblToken);
  //Set JSON Data in TextView
  gettoken.setText(token);
  } catch (JSONException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 }
 }
}
```

and this is my JSONParser class:-

```
package com.example.login1;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.util.Log;
public class JSONParser {
static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";
// constructor
public JSONParser() {
}
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
// Making HTTP request
try {
  // defaultHttpClient
  DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
  HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
  HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
  is = httpEntity.getContent();
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
      is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  String line = null;
  while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line + "n");
  }
  is.close();
  json = sb.toString();
} catch (Exception e) {
  Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
}
// try parse the string to a JSON object
try {
  jObj = new JSONObject(json);
} catch (JSONException e) {
  Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
}
// return JSON String
return jObj;
 }
}
```

*I am new with android and JSON, please help me. Thanks.*

```
//AndroidManifest.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.login1"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.login1.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Did you add permission in manifest-     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: to you tried to Sysout token? maybe you don't get the data.

Comment: post your manifest file

Comment: yes i have added the permission @Giru Bhai

Comment: Shouldn't all Network Thread actions be placed in an AsyncTask?

Comment: first of all you are doing all the network operation in main thread you should do it in Asynctask

Comment: use http call for get the data from the url or using the asynctask

Comment: And your JSON from the URL is "{
success: true,
result: {
token: "53ba8ad7cbe60",
serverTime: 1404734167,
expireTime: 1404734467
}
}", the curly braces is JSONObject and not JSONArray like you have called "json.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULT);"

Comment: @cokeby190 earlier it used to show android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException error

Comment: Terro is correct, use his answer, and change the array to object and try it out (:

Comment: I used the answer of TeRRo but an error came in it and when i fixed the error i.e. changed the type of token to JSONArray then an another error came below saying change type of token to string. How to fix it???

Comment: help!!! help!!! help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is surely **"android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException"** because you can not make an HTTP request in the UIThread. Use AsyncTask.

Change this:

```
TextView gettoken;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

    this.gettoken = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblToken);

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        String token;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            // Creating new JSON Parser
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            // Getting JSON from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            try {
                // Getting JSON Array
                token = json.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULT);
                JSONObject c = token.getJSONObject(0);
                // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                token = c.getString(TAG_TOKEN);
                //Importing TextView

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            //Set JSON Data in TextView
            gettoken.setText(token);
        }
    }.execute();

 }
```

Comment: Please do not suggest to change the `TheadPolicy` as part of your answer.

Comment: it shows errors in these two lines ' token = json.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULT);
                    JSONObject c = token.getJSONObject(0);'

Comment: @TeRRo it shows error in the data type used for token. What should I use for it, String or JSONArray???

Comment: Is it possible to show the error you are getting? You can add the the error to your existing question. Telling us simply that there is an error doesnt help us solve your problem.

Comment: @cokeby190 In  `token = json.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULT);` line, it shows Type Mismatch: Can not convert from JSONArray to String

Comment: and when I convert the data type of token to JSONArray, it starts showing erron in line  `token = c.getString(TAG_TOKEN);` saying Type Mismatch: Can not convert from String to JSONArray

Comment: It shouldbe something like "String token;
            
// Creating new JSON Parser
                JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
                // Getting JSON from URL
                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
                try {
                    // Getting JSON Array
                    JSONObject c= json.getJSONObject(TAG_RESULT);
                    // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                    token = c.getString(TAG_TOKEN);
"

Comment: Still showing error in line `JSONObject c = token.getJSONObject(TAG_RESULT);` ERROR :- _The methog getJSONObject(String) is undefined for the type String_

Answer (score 0):

Your `HttpPost` should be an `HttpGet`.  You want to pull data not push it.

Comment: Also Terro is correct - all network communication should be done in a separate thread, so an AsyncTask will help.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this method :

```
public String jsonTEST(String URL) {

    //new JSON parser instance
    JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();

    // getting JSON string from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL);

    try {
        JSONObject test = json.getJSONObject("result");

        return test.get string("token");


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

with the URL you provided, and I called it in this async task :

```
private class JsonGetTest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Object> {

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            String token = jsonTEST("https://demo.vtiger.com/webservice.php?operation=getchallenge&username=admin");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e;
        }
    }
```

And I called it with :

```
new JsonGetTest().execute();
```

And when i debug and looked at JSONObject test I saw this :

```
{"expireTime":1404744505,"token":"53bab20ddf1b5","serverTime":1404744205}
```

which is correct.

Comment: From where does this `JsonRequest` came??? Isn't working Sir, showing lot of errors :(

Comment: Sorry my bad. Editted.